# How to get table format output with sql query for a given table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

Can you please help me to get the query to get the below output table?

Thanks,

Input table

```
S   T   C
a   a   1
a   b   2   
a   c   3
a   d   4
b   a   5
b   b   6
b   c   7
b   d   8
c   a   9
c   b   10
c   c   11
c   d   12
d   a   13
d   b   14
d   c   15
d   d   16
```

Output table

```
S   a   b   c   d
a   1   2   3   4
b   5   6   7   8
c   9   10  11  12
d   13  14  15  16
```

Comment: I tried to play around with 'Pivot' and Case statement in select, but didn't get the expected output yet. Thanks.

Comment: If you know how pivot works in sql server, then the answer to this question is very easy. I wonder what you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer -

```
select * 
from
(
select S,T,C as Cd
from  Data
) as src
pivot(
Sum(Cd)--Max gives the same output too.
For T in ([a],[b],[c],[d])
) as pvt
```